# How can I get this game to loop until an user enters n?

Tags: java

What am I doing wrong?  I need the game to repeat until a user enters N or n.  Instead, it just keeps going and going and going......

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       int noOfPlayers;
       String playAgain;

       Scanner game = new Scanner(System.in);

       do {
       System.out.print("How many players in the game :");
       noOfPlayers = game.nextInt();
       if(noOfPlayers > 5) {
           System.out.println("Only 5 or less players can play.");
           System.out.println("How many players in the game (1-5) :");
           noOfPlayers = game.nextInt();
       }


       Game g=new Game(noOfPlayers);
       g.readPlayernames();
      
       g.playGame();
       
       System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y or N.");
       playAgain = game.next();      
              
    }
       while(playAgain != "Y" || playAgain !="y");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings cannot be compared with the == and != operators, they use the .equals. There is also a .equalsIgnore case that will help in your situation. For the while comparison, try while(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I think I got it!

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly duplicates. A link with an answer has already been given, no need to add another one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ChaocticDreamer is clearly a new programmer and your link did not help him. He did not figure out his issue until I answered, so that should get my answer voted up based on how stack defines the voting.

Comment: @rakers the post is closed by the Community user, which means ChaoticDreamer accepted the link as a duplicate to their question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca he obviously closed it after I answered or I would not have been able to even provide an answer. Also he commented under my answer saying I helped him and did not respond to you.